# Thread in Android programming

Tags: multithreading

Please see my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView01);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            txtView.setText(i + " ");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        txtView.setText("Main thread interrupted");
    }
}
}
```

The result of text view is 10. but when Thread Ends, The result will be displayed.
Merci.

Comment: Where's the thread that's ending?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to see, do you want all the numbers from 1 to 10 updated every second but you, correctly, only see 10? If that's what you want to see you can't do it right into OnCreate, add a specific thread(with update on the Main thread) or better add an AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes. i only see 10. how can i solve this?Merci.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this is a bit quick and dirty, and that there are cases in which it will not work right (for example, rotating the screen), but here it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView01);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            txtView.setText(i + " ");
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                txtView.setText("Counter thread interrupted");
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```